# How to sum up values in amount with duplicate date rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How to sum up values in amount with duplicate rows?

For example there are 2 unique dates. Can we do groupby? I'm expecting result like

```
Date         Amount
2019-07-01   20000000.....
2019-07-02   3000000000.....
```

The dataframe is below :

```
Date          Amount
2019-07-01    2,055,359.9800
2019-07-01    2,055,359.9800
2019-07-01    145198200
2019-07-01    145198200
2019-07-02    1,924,232.7200
2019-07-02    137,860,984.9000
2019-07-02    137,466,690.8800
2019-07-02    138,102,066.0400
2019-07-02    1,928,055.4400
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `groupby` the `Date` column and use `sum` to get the total `Amount` for each group.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-01',
                            '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02'],
                   'Amount': [2055359.9800, 145198200, 1924232.7200,
                              137860984.9000, 138102066.0400, 1928055.4400]})
print(df)

df2 = df.groupby(['Date']).sum()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                  Amount
Date                    
2019-07-01  1.491778e+08
2019-07-02  2.778911e+08
```

Comment: It's not working for big float numbers...

Comment: @NithinReddy Can you tell me what you mean by *not working*? It looks like it works for values in the question (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

sums = df.groupby(['Date']).sum()
```